# Recording the progress of RPG stats for historical graphing?

Tags: database, graph, theory, historical-db

Lets say I have a fighter who has the following basic attributes:

`{ cardio: 80, health: 80, punching: 25, kicking: 35 }`

I'm wanting to record the progress of the fighter over the course of a game, and show a `+` or `-`  on their progress; further I want to be able to put this stuff onto a graph to show the historical progress of a fighter's abilities.

The only thing I'm not sure about is how to construct my object to do this, or the the best way to record the data.

Thus my query is, how do I best record the progress of RPG stats for a fighter so that I might display a +/- of progress beside their name and also for historical graphing.

Many thanks

I am using Objective C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a web based game I would recommend a SQL database table for each player that stores those values and a timestamp as columns each time they change.
From that table you can get the data needed for the graph.

If its a desktop game that never uses a server, then you should store those values in a file.

You haven't specified the programming language you are using and many other things so its hard to tell.

Comment: I am using Objective C

Comment: Do you mean each player gets their own stats tables (playerStatsHistory) where I dump data with a timestamp and then do a query on a subset of time?

Comment: Yes. Each time a value changes you add a row with all the values and a timestamp. Then you use the timestamp as the x coord of the graph or to manage the values-rows you want to keep and the ones you can delete. Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a shot. I'll also read up on how finanical systems plot graphs for historical graphs

Comment: You'll need to take a look on how to store data in your hard drive, etc. and a library to plot graphs for objective C forms or equivalent. I'm more windows and pure openGL and DirectX oriented, so i don't know much about that.